# Defining tables that related many-to-many using MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, many-to-many, relational-database

I have a database with 3 tables, Roles, Departments and Users. I want a ManyToMany relationship between Users and Departments, and I want a ManyToMany relationship between Users and Roles. What techniques are used to define a many-to-many relationships using MySQL?

Comment: What would be the foreign key ?

Comment: If you don't know how to set this up, why are you creating a database?

Comment: @samitha I think that all of them would be foreign key, don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many to many connections you'll need a lookup table for each pair of tables.

```
users (user_id, username, password)
roles (role_id, role_name)
department (department_id, name, location)
users_roles (user_id, role_id)
  - user_id is a foreign key to users.user_id
  - role_id is a foreign key to role.role_id
  - user_id,role_id should be a unique key
users_departments (user_id, department_id)
  - user_id is a foreign key to users.user_id
  - department_id is a foreign key to department.department_id
  - user_id,department_id should be a unique key
```

**update**

Answering your question in the comments, you can use `JOIN` to combine the tables and use them to get data. For example to get users from given department (eg. department_id=1) and role (eg. role_id=2) you can do this:

```
SELECT `u`.*
FROM `users` AS `u`
    JOIN `users_roles` AS `ur` USING (`users_id`)
    JOIN `users_departments` AS `ud` USING (`users_id`)
WHERE `ur`.`role_id` = 2
    AND `ud`.`department_id` = 1
```

You can read more about how to use joins in the [JOIN article on the MySQL developer site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but with this structure, How I know who has Role = 1 in Department = 1?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see the restriction with this structure, this way, User=1 could have Role=1 and Role=2, both, in the same department, when only can have one Role.

Comment: You said "I want a ManyToMany relationship between Users and Roles". If you need many to many relations between users and departments and users and roles but only one role for a given user with a department, that's a new requirement. In that case you need a combined lookup table with (user_id, department_id, role_id) with a unique key on (user_id, department_id). But again, pay attention to the difference between the two situations.